# VSCode Missing Emmet Wrap Individual Lines with Abbreviation

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

The "wrapIndiviualLinesWithAbbreviation" command is missing completely from my VSCode. I have absolutely no command to keybind anything to. All other Emmet commands exist except for this one. I've tried a clean install to no avail. I'm on a work computer, so using the command line to wipe all traces of preferences and cache is a no go at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emmet wrap commands are combined into one `Emmet: Wrap with Abbeviation`

Comment: I guess I should read the change log more often. Lol. I thought my personal computer had the latest update, but apparently not because it still has two separate commands. Thank you sooooo much!